# VUE.JS API data by using axios show in V-data-table didn't work: it didn't show data

Tags: vue.js, axios, v-data-table

I am a beginner and I try to reach API and show the table by using Vue.js and Vuetify.
I got data from API but I can't show it by v-data-table.

This is my code:

HTML part

```
    <v-data-table :items="data" :headers="headers" :items-per-page="5">
       <template slot="data" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.data.userId }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.data.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.data.title }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

script part

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Current",
  data: () => ({
    items: ["albums", "todos", "posts"],
    selected: "",

    headers: [
      { text: "USER_ID", align: "start", sortable: false, value: "userId" },
      { text: "ID", value: "id" },
      { text: "TITLE", value: "title" },
    ],
    data:[],
  }),

  methods: {
    getData() {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/" + this.selected ,{dataType: 'json'})
        .then((response) => { this.data = response.data;})
        .catch((err) => alert(err));
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getData();
  }

};
</script>
```

### [Here is the output that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2qhY.png)

### [Here is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAMUu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code, first of all when you fetch data from json placeholder there is a single object in the response, you have to push that object to `data: []`, instead of assigning. Also, it looks like your `v-data-table` template looks weird, and values from headers should match a key name from response data.

```js
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table :items="data" :headers="headers" :items-per-page="5">
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "App",

  data: () => ({
    items: ["albums", "todos", "posts"],
    selected: "",

    headers: [
      { text: "USER_ID", align: "start", sortable: false, value: "id" },
      { text: "EMAIL", value: "email" },
      { text: "NAME", value: "name" },
    ],
    data: [],
  }),

  methods: {
    getData() {
      return axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/" + this.selected, {
          dataType: "json",
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.data.push(response.data)
        })
        .catch((err) => alert(err));
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getData();
  },
};
</script>
```